# why MenuContext is not working in Office Word 2016

Tags: office-js, office-addins, office-js-helpers

I'm trying to develop an office-js word add-ins to enhance the right-click menu but when I'm adding the element in my manifest . Word can't read/access the manifest anymore .
So OfficeMenu is not available for me .

What can I check ?

Many thanks

````
<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="ContextMenu">
            <OfficeMenu id="ContextMenuText">
              <Control xsi:type="Menu" id="ContextMenu2">
                <Label resid="CommandGroup.Label"/>
                <Supertip>
                  <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                  <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip"/>
                </Supertip>
                <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                  </Icon>
                  <Items>
                    <Item id="Item1">
                      <Label resid="IdItem1"/>
                      <Supertip>
                        <Title resid="IdItem1"/>
                        <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                      </Supertip>
                      <Icon>
                      <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                      <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                      <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                    </Icon>
                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                      <TaskpaneId>ButtonId1</TaskpaneId>
                      <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
                    </Action>
                  </Item>
                </Items>
              </Control>
            </OfficeMenu>
          </ExtensionPoint> ```
````

Comment: Does the manifest validate? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/troubleshoot-manifest. Also, what do you mean by Office can't access the manifest? What goes wrong and what steps lead up to it?

Comment: Hi Rick , yes running the npm run validate doesn't give any error and so the manifest is valid for the command . But Once I want to see the result in Word , I receiving an error message saying that the component(manifest) doesn't exist or has been moved /deleted . If I remove the lines about the menu , then it works again .

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think that I found the error .

I ran the runtime debugging module and I found that the issue was only due to a typo mistake

The following line 
`<Label resid="CommandGroup.Label"/>`
was referring to a the label Command**s**Group.Label so I was missing the S in the labelname and this is why the module was not loading properly